# media query for motorola e(2nd generation)

Tags: css, media-queries, motorola

```
   Media query for Motorola e(2nd generation). Kindly post the media query. @media only screen
```

and (min-width: 480px)
and (max-width: 960px) and (orientation:portrait) is not working

Answer (score 0):

your syntax may be wrong as posible so try this

```
@media screen and (min-width: 480px) and (max-width: 960px) {
    //Your Code
}
```

Comment: Yes I have tried this as well..It works. But it will affect even the i-phone as well..I need media query which will target only Motorola moto e(both portrait and landscape).. Thank you :)